# How to specify a compound command as an argument to another command?

Tags: bash, tor

Suppose `command1` takes another command (say `command2`) as argument, with `command2`'s arguments as the remaining arguments of `comman1`, i.e.

```
command1 command2 arg...
```

When `command2` is a made up of several commands (each of which might have its own arguments and options), e.g. when `command2` is `command 3; command 4` and `command 3 | command 4`, how do you specify `command2` as an argument to `command1`?

Does my question belong to bash, `command1`, or both?

1. The solution I can think of is: writing `command2` as a bash script
   and passing the script name in place of `command2` as an argument to
   `command1`.

   But it seems not work in the following example:

   ```
   $ torify /tmp/test-tor/download.sh
   /usr/bin/torsocks: 162: exec: /tmp/test-tor/download.sh: not found
   ```

   where the content of `/tmp/test-tor/download.sh` is:

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/bash

   curl ifconfig.me 
   myprogram -n myarg
   ```
2. I also would like to know if it is possible to solve the problem without writing a
   script, because it seems overkill to write a script when `command2`
   is short.

   For example, when using `tor` with a program, I want to check my
   external ip address by `curl ifconfig.me`, before running the
   program

   ```
   torify "curl ifconfig.me; myprogram -n myarg"
   ```

   but it doesn't work.

Comment: searching for torify using google is bringing up tor project related web pages. I am pretty sure there is a large user comunity behind the tor project and at least a few discussion boards and/or mailing lists. Did you try asking this question there. Because, if your script is there and torify is telling you it can not find it, this might be because of the default  behavior of tor, not necessarily bash.

Comment: it seems that `torify` is a wrappter of `torsocks`, which is in turn a wrapper of `tor`.

Comment: Yeah, and I remember a lot of nastiness going about tor, like people's real addresses being discovered and such not too long time ago. This behavior of tor might be intentional. You might need to tweak it a little. I am by no means a tor user or know anything about it. Hence, can't be much help.

Comment: Closely related: [What is the difference between running a command directly and with ‘bash -c’?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276581/80216#276611)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The following links may not be the actual version you have, but are probably similar enough]. The `torify` command is a [shell script](https://github.com/arlolra/tor/blob/master/contrib/client-tools/torify),
which just calls `torsocks` which is another [shell script](https://github.com/dgoulet/torsocks/blob/master/src/bin/torsocks.in) that just does `exec`.

So you should just be able to provide multiple commands to `torify` like this:

```
torify sh -c 'curl ifconfig.me; myprogram -n myarg'
```

The problem you have with `torify /tmp/test-tor/download.sh` is probably that the script you wrote should start with `#!/bin/bash`; some systems don't have a `/usr/bin/bash`. Make sure you `chmod +x` your script too.